# The provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is not registered SSAS Tabular Model

Tags: ssis, ssas, windows-server-2012-r2, import-from-excel, sql-server-2016

I have a 64-Bit machine (Windows Server 2012 R2), MS Office 2013 Standard-64 bit  install, SQL Server 2014 install. When I installed 'Access Database Engine Redistributable 64 bit', I am not been able to import the data from Excel file(.xlsx) using 'Import/Export wizard' and even through SSIS package. I uninstall the  'Access Database Engine Redistributable 64 bit' and install  Access Database Engine Redistributable 32 bit after that my 'Import/Export Wizard' and SSIS package working like a charm.
Now I have to create a 'SSAS Tabular Model' and some data is directly coming via Excel file. when I am trying to create a connection from excel file I am again getting the same error 'The provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is not registered'.

I know it is very common problem and lots of solution are already there i tried most of them and non of it actaully work for me.

If anyone have any idea regarding this please post or let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Regards,
Piyush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

See the solution [Here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting159.htm)